# Smooth scrolling - whole page, not just to anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

i've searched through the site for any examples but i can't find what i'm looking for. Basically i've implemented smooth scrolling to an anchor point on [my site here](http://www.dxsxgn.com) but i want to force a smooth scrolling effect for the entire page, not just when a link is clicked. This is the site i found and wanted to replicate: [www.toolofna.com/#/about](http://www.toolofna.com/#/about). They have managed to force Chrome on Windows, without the smooth scroll extension, to only scroll smoothly, as opposed to scrolling say 50px at a time as every notch on my scroll wheel is passed. Does anyone have any idea how i might get about implementing this?

Thanks.

Note - This is being marked as a duplicate question by people who don't seem to be reading what i have written. I have a link to a page above which shows a site which changes the scrolling to be pixel-by-pixel smooth movement, which i am trying to achieve. The answers provided don't address the issue i'm talking about  -  i have managed to understand smooth scrolling to anchor links using jQuery scrollTo, but i want this to be enabled for the whole site. For example, when clicking directly on the scroll bar, you can scroll slowly, or fast, or by however much you want. With a standard mouse on Windows (OSX may handle this differently, and on Windows 8 using touch works smoothly) the scrolling is at a set speed and a set amount of movement.

i understand it is probably frustrating when it looks like someone is asking a question that is similar to another, but i'm not daft - i have searched through all answers and found nothing to help. Some people's answers on this site are frankly unhelpful and sometimes rude; I'm inexperienced and obviously need some help with this, so unhelpful answers and blindly marking a question as duplicated is not really fair.

Comment: I've looked at this thread and unfortunately it doesn't help: i'm looking for smooth vertical scrolling, and the solutions provided in the thread don't implement the smooth scrolling i'm looking for: to expand more, is it possible to force the amount of pixels which are scrolled by? for example, one 'notch' on the scrollwheel is 1 pixel on the screen?

Comment: The users sets this in their mouse preferences. I don't think you can change it, nor would I want a site to make that decision for me.

Comment: I understand that. Have you checked the site i mentioned in my original post? This isn't an invasive method, on my site it would only serve to make my CSS3D transforms more obvious, as normal scrolling on my PC without actually using the scrollbar means the animation is missed completely.

Comment: Have you read this already ? http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/

Comment: I have seen this page and it still isn't what i'm looking for :( thanks anyway though.